# How to add a link to Wordpress Plugin install Listing

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

When an user searches for a plugin from the WP Admin's Add Plugin area, I want to add a link/button to every plugin's listing area.

**Which hook should I use?**

The location where I want the link is marked in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the filter: [`"plugin_install_action_links"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_install_action_links/).

You can find this in [`/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php) (currently) at line 434:

```
$action_links = apply_filters( 'plugin_install_action_links', $action_links, $plugin );
```

Use it like:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_install_action_links', 'my_custom_links', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_links( $action_links, $plugin ){
    $action_links[] = '<a href="">......</a>';
    return $action_links;
}
```